# Vaulted ceiling cracked paint

Tags: ceiling, paint, cracks

I’m not sure if it’s from old paint or if it’s a sign of water damage but my ceiling paint in the v is cracking. Suggestions on what to look out for? It’s so high I can’t get to it myself[image]

Comment: Crack looks like dubious drywall work, and not terribly concerning of itself. If there are others, or it gets larger, perhaps revisit/reassess. I would not get overly stressed about it based on this one picture, and put off "fixing" it until you're doing some sort of work that involves staging to get up to ceiling level for some other reason.

Comment: Yep, that looks exactly like drywall tape and mud separating at the joint.  You say it's hard to get to, so monitor as best you can.  If you could get to it, I'd try filling the gap with joint compound.  Since JC is rigid, if the cracks reappear you still have movement at the joint.

Comment: As mentioned above, the tape is bubbling and the joint has opened up because of movement. Try using a siliconized paintable acrylic caulking to fill the joint.